# How can I edit One Property and Display Another using a UITypeEditor Custom Type

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I am using a `PropertyGrid` control in my WinForms with a custom type editor and this works fine but now I want to display one value in the property grid and edit another.

The property is a zero - many selection of "Cost Centres", so I want to display the Cost Centre Description but save back the Cost Centre code.

Originally I was doing a description to code lookup after editing, but the description may not be unique (whereas the codes are)

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: The PG uses a TypeConverter when it displays a value and an UITypeEditor when it edit the value, which should allow you to do what you need, I believe.